# Why do you serialize an object for a database?

Tags: serialization

I know what serializing means but not really how to apply it.  When do you serialize an object for a database.  Doesn't matter the language but here is [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

```
<?php
// $session_data contains a multi-dimensional array with session
// information for the current user.  We use serialize() to store
// it in a database at the end of the request.

$conn = odbc_connect("webdb", "php", "chicken");
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn,
      "UPDATE sessions SET data = ? WHERE id = ?");
$sqldata = array (serialize($session_data), $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
if (!odbc_execute($stmt, $sqldata)) {
    $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn,
     "INSERT INTO sessions (id, data) VALUES(?, ?)");
    if (!odbc_execute($stmt, $sqldata)) {
        /* Something went wrong.. */
    }
}
?>
```

Why would I do this?  Why wouldn't I just use a regular query execute for update or insert.  I read the code comments but I'm not grasping it.

EDIT:  What kind of information is in that session_data that I'd need to not have in a regular column?

Answer (score 1):

Serialization typically is used to send objects between applications (machines, processes sometimes) through a data stream, for example - web service communication over HTTP protocol, socket communication etc. In the context of databases serialization is needed only when an object, or some part of it can't be fully stored in columns as values of it's properties. Such scenario can occur if you are forced to store some new data, but can't update database's existing schema. Then you perhaps use some varchar column to store some more data in the XML format, for example. It is of course discouraged, however sometimes when you work with legacy code there is no other way.

Comment: What kind of objects would I send that is not going to a database that has to be saved?  Or is there something else serialized for a database I'd send?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking about. Any object in your application can be sent/persisted. It depends heavily on the context. Maybe I could be more helpful if you asked a more precise question.

Answer (score 0):

databases (and other external storage / transmission systems) work on blocks of bytes. Thus somebody needs to convert what you have in memory to a block of bytes that can also be converted back to what you originally had in memory. For some things this is trivial and the system (PHP, db, ..) knows how to do it (string for example). But you can have a really complicated things in memory - a dictionary of arrays for example. Somebody has to make that into a contiguous recoverable block of bytes (serialize) and also provide a way to convert the block back to the original in memory data (deserialize)